# fully Controlled Bridge with BT151

Tags: dc-motor, h-bridge, scr

I have tried BT151 for my half bridge controller to drive a DC motor. unlikely, it doesn't work. I would be grateful if you help me through this question. [image].

Comment: Be more specific. Explain what you mean by "doesn't work".

Comment: The circuit you show is for AC. Do you use AC to drive your DC motor? Or do you use the circuit with DC? Neither is likely to work.

Comment: Also, it looks like your schematic has the load and source mixed up, and the ground is in a very strange place. What makes you think this is an appropriate circuit for your DC motor?

Comment: @uint128_t I have checked the 4n33 output's voltage , unfortunately it shows me nothing , could you help me how can I turn on this opto while there is a sufficient current for the thyristor ?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen for the fully bridge controlled we have this formula for the output Voltage from the source ( 2Vm/pi)*Cos(alpha) . Alpha is the firing angle.

Comment: @uint128_t my another question is that the ground of the load equals to the ground of the 4n33's emitter ?

Comment: @ashkansed Answer Wouter's question first: You have a DC motor and an AC motor control circuit, what are you actually trying to do.

Comment: @uint128_t I am trying to use that formula to make a dc output , actually its not a dc voltage , its an Integral of the input voltage when it had been fired

Comment: no, **why are you using an AC motor controller with a DC motor**, **what is your intention**. Not "what are you currently trying to do to solve the acute problems". Google for "XY problem" to understand why we're asking.

Comment: You talk a lot about formulas and cos(alpha) but that is **irrelevant** if you use the wrong circuit for implementing what you want. You do not seem to understand that your circuit probably **cannot even work**. At least, I have my doubts about it as I have never seen this construction before. You avoid answering questions about **how the circuit is supposed to work** and that tells me that you do not have a clue. But if I'm wrong, please prove me wrong so we can all learn something. Circuit design is seldom about only knowing a certain formula. Formula people are the worst circuit designers.

Comment: @MarcusMüller what I am doing to do is based on this link 
Herzlichen Dank herr Müller

http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1274114&page_number=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with this circuit:-

1. SCR triggering is applied between Gate and Cathode. You cannot join the Gates of two SCRs which have different Cathode potentials (D1 and D3, D2 and D4). Each must have its own Gate drive referenced to its own Cathode.

You will need 4 optocouplers, each with its own isolated 5V supply 'grounded' to the Cathode of the SCR it is driving (where two Cathodes are joined they can share the same supply).

2. Your voltages are too low.

V1 and V2 signals should be ~0-5V, and V3 must be several volts (at least) to exceed the SCR on-state voltages.

3. With a 10Ω pullup resistor to 5V the optocoupler has to sink almost 500mA to keep the SCR turned off. The 4N33 is rated for 150mA absolute maximum.

You could increase the pullup resistor value to 220Ω and still have enough trigger current, but the optocoupler's saturation voltage is ~2V which won't be enough to keep the SCR turned off. This can be fixed by connecting the optocoupler in *series* with the resistor, so it triggers the SCR when turned on.

Comment: I appreciate your comment.
one thing has been left , by "by connecting the optocoupler in series with the resistor" do you mean I should put a resistor in its Emitters or in the SCR's gate ? I will be thankful if you let me know how much should that transistor be rated ?

Comment: I mean instead of connecting the optocoupler from the resistor to 'ground' (SCR Source) wire it in series with the resistor (eg. Collector to +5V, Emitter to resistor, resistor to Gate). Since the optocoupler drops ~2V, you should make the resistor value ~100 Ohms, which should set the trigger current to ~20mA.

Comment: I have used your meaningful suggestions for the resistors and it finally works. unfortunately there is a voltage drop for the SCR , as I used an opto with a single SCR , when I cheked the open anode cathode voltage without any load it was about 5V instead of 12 volts, when I add a 10Ohms load between anode and cathode the voltage on the load was about 1 volt ( instead of 12 volts)
I would be grateful if you help me.
thank you in advance

Comment: I would like to help but this is not the place to do it. Open another question and show us your new circuit, or continue this conversation in chat.